# why IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

It's a asp.net core project.
here is my code.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddJwtBearer(...);
 services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
 services.TryAddSingleton<IUserInfo,UserInfo>();
```

First code:

```
public class UserInfo : IUserInfo
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserInfo(IHttpContextAccessor iHttpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = iHttpContextAccessor;
    }

    public UserData GetUserData()
    {
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
           // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Second code:

```
public class UserInfo : IUserInfo
{
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public UserInfo(IHttpContextAccessor iHttpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContext= iHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public UserData GetUserData()
    {
        if (_httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

When i use first code in `Action`, it's fine. `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]` has my token and `IsAuthenticated` is true.

But when i use second code , it can not work. `HttpContext` is not correct. `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]` is Empty and `IsAuthenticated` is false.

I want to know that is why,thanks.

If you don't understand my words,i'm sorry for this,my English is very bad......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IUserInfo,UserInfo` is registered as a singleton so it will only be initialized once.(remember that, it is important)

In the first example, every time `GetUserData()` is called `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` returns the current request's `HttpContext`.

In the second example the `HttpContext` will only be set once in the singleton class's constructor. That means that every time `GetUserData()` is called you will get the very same context that was set the first time it was initialized. Which would mean the context being used would not be the context of the current request as the request would not be available as yet when the class was being initialized.

The first example is the suggested way to access the current `HttpContext`.

Comment: Thank you!I understand,you are so nice.

Comment: Every request,_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext will be reset,it is new HttpContext,can i understand like this?

Comment: @hank.yao I did not understand you last comment. Can you reword it to clarify what you want to know.

Comment: What I mean is that when there is a new request, the program will regenerate the httpcontext instance, so _ihttpcontextaccessor.httpcontext will be a new object ,not modify the value of the property in the original httpcontext instance. And _httpcontext still refers to the first generated httpcontext instance, which is why the second code does not work.
Am i right?
Can you understand my words?i am sorry,my english is very bad(╥_╥)

Comment: @hank.yao yes that is correct. The context is constructed based on the current request. The instance in the second example wont change on every request as you described.